# Generate a value and view in another PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Im getting values from a dynamic form (create.php) to this page (gen.php). what I want to do is generate $gresult values for given number of amount and if the value is already in database generate again. and view generated values in create.php.

process is get $binnumber from db as per the form dropdown > generate a random number $randomnumber > merge two values $binandrand > run it through luhn algo in luhn.php > get the check value $gresult. merge $binandrand and $gresult > display values on create.php (in a table).

I do understand I should add a dowhile loop for this but Im stuck on how to add it. A help on this would be great.

```
 <?php
    include 'server.php';


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $binnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_REQUEST['modelname']);
    $randomnumber = mt_rand(100000,999999);
    $binandrand = $binnumber.$randomnumber;


        include_once 'Luhn.php';
        $luhn = new Luhn();
        if ($_POST['action'] == "calculate" && isset($_POST['gnumber'])) {
            $gnumber = $binandrand;
            $gresult = $luhn->calculate($gnumber);

        }  else {
                $vresult = "Number is invalid";
            }



    echo "<br/>";
    echo "test";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $binnumber;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $randomnumber;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $binandrand;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $gresult;
    }
    ?>
```

below is the Luhn() function. which I found on internet

```
<?php
/**
 * Luhn algorithm (a.k.a. modulus 10) is a simple formula used to validate variety of identification numbers.
 * It is not intended to be a cyrptographically secure hash function, it was designed to protect against accidental errors.
 * See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm
 * 
 * @author Rolands Kusiņš
 * @version 0.2
 * @license GPL
 */

class Luhn {
    private $sumTable = array(array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), array(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9));

    /**
     * Calculate check digit according to Luhn's algorithm
     * New method (suggested by H.Johnson), see http://www.phpclasses.org/discuss/package/8471/thread/1/
     * 
     * @param string $number
     * @return integer
     */
    public function calculate($number)
    {
        $length = strlen($number);
        $sum = 0;
        $flip = 1;
        // Sum digits (last one is check digit, which is not in parameter)
        for($i = $length-1; $i >= 0; --$i) $sum += $this->sumTable[$flip++ & 0x1][$number[$i]];
        // Multiply by 9
        $sum *= 9;
        // Last digit of sum is check digit
        return (int)substr($sum, -1, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate check digit according to Luhn's algorithm
     * This is an old method, tests show that this is little bit slower than new one
     * 
     * @param string $number
     * @return integer
     */
    public function calculateOld($number) {
        $length = strlen($number);
        $sum = 0;
        $p = $length % 2;
        // Sum digits, where every second digit from right is doubled (last one is check digit, which is not in parameter)
        for($i = $length-1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
            $digit = $number[$i];
            // Every second digit is doubled
            if ($i % 2 != $p) {
                $digit *= 2;
                // If doubled value is 10 or more (for example 13), then add to sum each digit (i.e. 1 and 3)
                if($digit > 9){
                    $sum += $digit[0];
                    $sum += $digit[1];
                } else{
                    $sum += $digit;
                }
            } else{
                $sum += $digit;
            }
        }
        // Multiply by 9
        $sum *= 9;
        // Last one is check digit
        return (int)substr($sum, -1, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Validate number against check digit
     * 
     * @param string $number
     * @param integer $digit
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function validate($number,$digit){
        $calculated = $this->calculate($number);
        if($digit == $calculated) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
?>
```

-----Update -----

I manage to create a while loop, but now I need to get generated values to create.php in html table.

```
<?php
include 'server.php';
//Get all brand data
    $query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM brand ORDER BY brandname ASC");
    $query1 = $connection->query("select * from model");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['action'])) {
$binnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_REQUEST['modelname']);
$noemi = $_REQUEST['nofoemei'];
//$randomnumber = mt_rand(100000,999999);
//$binandrand = $binnumber.$randomnumber;
//$imeinumber = $binandrand.$gresult;


    include_once 'Luhn.php';



    if ($_POST['action'] == "calculate" && isset($_POST['gnumber'])) {

        //=======================
        $x1 =0;
        //0 1       3
    while ($x1 < $noemi) {
  //echo "The number is:================= $x1 <br>";
 $randomnumber = mt_rand(10,99);
         $binandrand = $binnumber.$randomnumber;
         $gnumber = $binandrand;
         $luhn = new Luhn();
         $gresult = $luhn->calculate($gnumber);
        $tt = $binandrand.$gresult;

        $imei_check_query = "SELECT * FROM imeinumbers WHERE imeinumber='$tt' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $imei_check_query);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0){
         echo "  result   <br>";


        }else{

         echo $tt;
         echo "<br/>";
         ++$x1;
        }

            }

        //==================
        /*
        for ($x = 0; $x < $noemi; $x++) {

         $randomnumber = mt_rand(10,99);
         $binandrand = $binnumber.$randomnumber;
         $gnumber = $binandrand;
         $luhn = new Luhn();
         $gresult = $luhn->calculate($gnumber);
        $tt = $binandrand.$gresult;

        $imei_check_query = "SELECT * FROM imeinumbers WHERE imeinumber='$tt' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $imei_check_query);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0){
         echo "  result   <br>";

          //++$x1;
        }else{
         echo "NO result   <br>";
        }

         //$binandrandX = $binnumber.$randomnumber;
          echo "The number is+++++++++++++++++++++++ $x <br>";
        }
        */

        //$imei_avail = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            //if($imei_avail){
            //  if($imei_avail['imeinumber']===$imeinumber){
            //      
            //  }
            //}

    }  else {
            $vresult = "Number is invalid";
        }



echo "<br/>";
echo "tttttttt".$noemi;
echo "<br/>";
echo $binnumber;
echo "<br/>";
echo $randomnumber;
echo "<br/>";
echo $binandrand;
echo "<br/>";
echo $gresult;
echo "<br/>";
//echo $imeinumber;
echo "<br/>";
//echo $nofoemei;
}
?>
```

Comment: Would you please put the " $luhn->calculate() " this function details. And it's little bit hard to understand your question.

Comment: @ArafHossain I have added the $luhn function details

Comment: where are you fetching database? is that function in the Create.php? 
if yes then would you please also put that that function?

Comment: @ArafHossain - I have updated the final code with the loop. now I need to get values ($tt) to create.php

Comment: just get the value in the variable and then include that file in your create.php and then call that value. 
[checkout this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135131/php-getting-variable-from-another-php-file)

Comment: or you may can do it with $_SESSION['number']

Comment: @ArafHossain is it possible to get values without refresh with  $_SESSION['number'], can you explain it. thank you.

Comment: sorry for my late. I don't know what are you saying but I am explaining what I just understand. 
If you put any value to the session it doesn't change or destroy if you don't want to. Also you can access that session value from anywhere. 

And yes you can get values with ajax without refresh. [Checkout this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894940/setting-php-session-variables-with-ajax)